# Janela modal com conteúdo do banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Eu até sei os PHP e Javascript, o problema é que eu não sei como criar o modal de forma dinâmica para cada clique em um link, trazer informações especificas daquele link. Se clicar no *usuário 1*, trazer informações na janela modal do usuário 1, se clicar no *usuário 2*, mostrar informações do usuário 2, e assim por diante.

Eis o que eu tenho até agora, não sou muito experiente em Jquery, creio que dai a minha maior dificuldade em resolver esse problema

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Show modal box
    $('.showdialog').click(function(e) {                            
        $('#dialog').show();
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    //Hide modal box        
    $('.closeModal').click(function(){
        $('.mask').hide();
    }); 
}); 

<a href="?acao=editar&idusuario=1" class="showindow">Usuário 1</a>
<a href="?acao=editar&idusuario=2" class="showindow">Usuário 2</a>
```

Segue-se uma lista de links vindos do banco de dados, nos resultados do banco, não tem erro, fora da janela os resultados aparecem normalmente.

Comment: Não sabe PHP com DB, ou não sabe criar o modal? Veja um exemplo de [*modal*](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: [Duplicata](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31812/janela-modal-exibir-conte%C3%BAdo-vindo-do-banco-de-dados-mysql-php)

Comment: Eu até sei os dois, o problema é que eu não sei como criar o modal de forma dinâmica, a cada clique em um link, trazer informações especificas daquele link, Se clicar no usuário 1, trazer informações na janela modal do usuário 1, se clicar no 2, mostrar informações do usuário 2, e assim por diante,espero que tenha ficado claro!!!

Comment: JS é bem flexível e acaba tendo N respostas com o mesmo efeito, então recomendo você mostrar o que tem feito para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Bom, desculpe se não ajudar. Mas eu faria assim: as informações poderiam vir via ajax. Eu passaria como parametro o id do usuario e retornaria todos os dados dele. No momento em que o ajax devolvesse esses dados eu criaria o html do modal e ativaria o modal com o js. Se achar que isso ajuda eu monto um código de exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Criei um [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jty0y92/3/) bem básico. O loop vai criar uma div oculta para receber as informações e o modal vai usa-las e aceita formatação. Espero que sirva como base para você montar seu modelo.

Seu loop monta uma div `id="usuario1"` para link e uma div `id="data_usuario1"` com a formatação em *HTML*.

<sub>**JS**</sub>

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $("#conteudoModal").html($('#data_'+id).text());
    });
});
```

<sub>**HTML / PHP**</sub>

Opção manual

```
<a href="#" id="usuario1">usuário 1</a><br>
<div id="data_usuario1" style="display:none">Dados do usuário 1</div>
```

Opção simulando loop de registros

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    echo '<a href="#" id="usuario'.$i.'">usuário '.$i.'</a><br>';
    echo '<div id="data_usuario'.$i.'" style="display:none">Dados do usuário '.$i.'</div>';
}
```

Html da janela modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Paginas</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="conteudoModal"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

<sub>**arquivos**</sub>

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Papa Charlie!!! o código que você mandou funciona do jeito que eu preciso, vou adaptar ao meu projeto!!!

Comment: @Wilerson Vaz, se resolveu, clique na resposta para aceitar e de uma lida no FAQ [como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @WilersonVaz, confira o guia [*Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/201)

Answer (score 0):

Olá pessoal queria ajuda de vocês, eu fiz o exemplo passado acima e funcionou, porém eu apliquei em meu projeto e não estou tendo sucesso, será que vocês podem me ajudar?
Abaixo os códigos utilizados.

echo ''

```
echo '<div id="sequencial_'.$sequencial.'" style="display:none">'.$sequencial.'</div>';
echo '<div id="descricao_'.$sequencial.'" style="display:none">'.$descricao.'</div>';
echo '<div id="quantidade_'.$sequencial.'" style="display:none">'.$quantidade.'</div>';
echo '<div id="valor_item_'.$sequencial.'" style="display:none">'.$valor_item.'</div>';
```

e abaixo o javascript

```
<script>
$("a").click(function () {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#myModal').modal('show');        

    document.getElementById('edtdescricao').value  = $('#descricao_'+id).html(); 
    document.getElementById('edtquantidade').value = $('#quantidade_'+id).html(); 
    document.getElementById('edtvalor_item').value = $('#valor_item_'+id).html(); 
    document.getElementById('edtsequencial').value = $('#sequencial_'+id).html(); 
});
```

Comment: criei também um JSFiddle porém tem o php misturado não tem como rodar por lá. http://jsfiddle.net/EdersonFrasson/uoraepsj/1/